# Desktop shortcut to restart a windows service

Tags: windows, windows-services, shortcut-file

Is it possible to create a windows desktop shortcut that will restart a windows service?

I'd like a button to restart my apache service after I have made changes to the config file.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do this in a batch file, then make a shortcut to it.

Create a text file with the following content, but save it with the file extension .bat

```
net stop "Service Name"
net start "Service Name"
```

Once the file exists, you can create a shortcut to it, and even assign a keyboard shortcut too if deemed necessary.

Comment: Consider using of **sc** instead of **net** (see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12188261/971141)). **sc** is non-blocking since it only sends a message to manipulate service.

Answer (score 27):

You can accomplish this without a batch file using the following shortcut target:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "net stop "Service Name" & net start "Service Name""
```

In addition to the answer the following comment by Tibo is mandatory:

> To make it run as Administrator (required for some services, maybe all?), in the shortcut's properties window, tab Shortcut, clic on the button "Advanced..." (at the bottom) then check "Run as administrator". It will open the User Account Control popup each time.

Comment: To make it run as Administrator (required for some services, maybe all?), in the shortcut's properties window, tab Shortcut, clic on the button "Advanced..." (at the bottom) then check "Run as administrator". It will open the User Account Control popup each time.

Comment: Needed to use && to make it work

Answer (score 17):

I'm using a system consisting of a simple CMD batch script and an LNK shortcut. The batch script contains the [**`sc` command**](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html), which acts as a Windows services controller. For starting or stopping a service it uses the same parameters as the [`net` command](https://ss64.com/nt/net-service.html):

`sc <start|stop> <service>`

So, e.g. for starting Apache web server service and MySQL database server service, the batch script named `web_servers_start.cmd` could look like the following:

```
sc start "Apache2.2"
sc start MySQL
```

The batch script must be launched elevated as an administrator. So I created a **LNK shortcut** which points to the batch script `web_servers_start.cmd` and checked "*Run as administrator*" in the file's *Properties* dialog under the "*Advanced...*" button on the *Shortcut tab*.

You can place the LNK shortcut on the desktop, start menu or wherever you prefer.

**Note:** One of differences between the `sc` and `net` commands is that `sc` sends a message (e.g. `start`) to a service and ends itself immediately while `net` waits until service operation is done. If you don't need to manipulate with operation status or error code, `sc` command is much faster.

Comment: thanx your answer helped me but in windows 7 i need to right click on the shortcut and run as admin.. and as you said to  check the run as admin.. checkbox in properties.. unfortunately the checkbox is disabble... help plz.

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to set it for CMD file, instead of for **LNK** one? I have disabled that option for CMD file too, but LNK has it enabled.

Comment: I have it disabled on lnk too.